# How to place Images next to RadioButton in RadioGroup?

Tags: android

I am making a Q&A app. I will have text answers and images as answers, so I will check from DB and when I have text answers I will display it with the radio button because it's view is similar to `TextView`, but the problem comes if I have images as answers. So I'd like to place an `ImageView` next to my `RadioButton` which is in `RadioGroup`, but I don't know the right way. I tried with `RelativeLayout` inside  the `RadioGroup` but I am losing the functionality of the buttons... Here is picture of how it looks with text answers

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rawj0.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to go around it according to me-:
Preferred-:

```
[Link][1]
```

ToRightOf is a method to go round it

**OR**

Change the
android:right in xml

Comment: Yes, toRightOf / toLeftOf was the first thing that came on my mind, but it says `Invalid layout param in RadioGroup: layout_toLeftOf` ...

Comment: Then you can use the 2nd less preffered method...Use android:right or android:left or margin options to resolve it... If you can't find a better alternative.